# Is the limit of $x/\sin x$ as $x\to 0$ equal to $1$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Since  $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$

Will $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{\sin x} = 1$ also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from the *algebraic limit theorem*, which states, in part, that if $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ exists and is not $0$, then $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{f(x)}=\frac{1}{\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)}.$$ This is the same theorem which allows you to multiply and add limits together.

Answer (score 1):

One way to show this limit is to recall that the sine function is bounded by

$$|x\cos x|\le |\sin x|\le |x|$$

For $0<|x|<\pi/2$, we can take reciprocals and find that

$$\frac{1}{\cos x}\ge \frac{x}{\sin x}\ge 1$$

Therefore, by the squeeze theorem we have

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{\sin x}=1$$

as expected!